# Related to ProcessStartInfo() method in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Related to ProcessStartInfo() method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311820/related-to-processstartinfo-method-in-c)

I want to pass these arguments in `ProcessStartInfo(F:\\Android\\android-sdk-windows\\platform-tools>adb.exe install F:\\P1\\bin\\ANDPROJ1-debug.apk)`
so i am passing these arguments just below here but I am getting a exception that `The system cannot find the file specified`.

Plz give me solution why this error is coming whereas I am checking all the path correctly.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo androidInstallInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
androidInstallInfo.FileName ="adb.exe";
androidInstallInfo.Arguments = "install F:\\P1\\bin\\ANDPROJ1-debug.apk"; //"install"+" "+ProjectLocation+"\\" + "bin\\" + ProjectName + "-debug.apk";;
androidInstallInfo.WorkingDirectory = F:\\Android\\android-sdk-windows\\platform-tools; 
androidInstallInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
androidInstallInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
androidInstallInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process androidProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
androidProcess.StartInfo = androidInstallInfo;
androidProcess.Start();
androidProcess.Close();
```

Comment: have you not noticed the pattern yet? Stop posting new questions that duplicate your existing question. If you have more info to add, edit your existing question.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to set the full path to adb.exe - presumably -

```
F:\\Android\\android-sdk-windows\\platform-tools\\adb.exe
```

Comment: But i want to execute this adb.exe file on this directory so i am giving filename ="adb.exe" individually.

Comment: I have tried ur suggestion but not workng yet now and give the error as usual.